# Pivot SQL with Rank

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Basically i have the following query and i am trying to distinguish only the unique ranks from this:

```
    WITH numbered_rows
    as (
    SELECT Claim,
           reserve,
           time,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ClaimNumber ORDER BY time asc) as 'Rank'
   FROM (          
   SELECT cc.Claim, 
          MAX(csd.time) as time,
          csd.reserve

   FROM ClaimData csd WITH (NOLOCK) 

        JOIN Core cc WITH (NOLOCK) 
            on cc.ClaimID = csd.ClaimID

    GROUP BY cc.Claim, csd.Reserve

        ) as t
    ) 
    select  *
    from numbered_rows cur, numbered_rows prev
    where cur.Claim= prev.Claim
          and cur.Rank = prev.Rank -1
```

The results set I get is the following:

```
Claim  reserve  Time        Rank  Claim  reserve    Time     Rank
--------------------------------------------------------------------
11     0        12/10/2012  1     11     15000    5/30/2013  2
34     2000     1/21/2013   1     34     750      1/31/2013  2
34     750      1/31/2013   2     34     0        3/31/2013  3
07     800000   5/9/2013    1     07     0        5/10/2013  2
```

But what I only want to see the following: (have the Claim 34 Rank 2 removed because its not the highest

```
Claim  reserve  Time        Rank  Claim  reserve    Time     Rank
--------------------------------------------------------------------
11     0        12/10/2012  1     11     15000    5/30/2013  2
34     750      1/31/2013   2     34     0        3/31/2013  3
07     800000   5/9/2013    1     07     0        5/10/2013  2
```

Comment: By the use of the SQL Server [Turbo button](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2684/418) I'd bet you're right.

Comment: Yes!SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: *"have the Claim 34 Rank 2 removed because its not the highest"* - however, you have removed the Claim 34 Rank 1 record from the desired result set, which **is** the highest. Please can you clarify your question?

Comment: @MarkBannister: Perhaps by the *highest* Emily means the highest *ranking* (=greatest ranking number)?

Comment: The Claim 34 Rank2 from table prev should be removed.I only want to see the max per claim for the rank in the current table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this by just reversing your logic, i.e. order by time DESC, switching cur and prev in your final select and changing -1 to +1 in your final select, then just limiting prev.rank to 1, therefore ensuring that the you only include the latest 2 results for each claim:

```
WITH numbered_rows AS
(   SELECT  Claim,
            reserve,
            time,
            [Rank] = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ClaimNumber ORDER BY time DESC)
    FROM    (   SELECT  cc.Claim, 
                        [Time] = MAX(csd.time),
                        csd.reserve
                FROM    ClaimData AS csd WITH (NOLOCK) 
                        INNER JOIN JOIN Core AS cc WITH (NOLOCK) 
                            ON cc.ClaimID = csd.ClaimID
                GROUP BY cc.Claim, csd.Reserve
            ) t
)
SELECT  *
FROM    numbered_rows AS prev
        INNER JOIN numbered_rows AS cur
            ON cur.Claim= prev.Claim
            AND cur.Rank = prev.Rank + 1
WHERE   prev.Rank = 1;
```

Comment: @EmilyD: Then please use the check mark on the left to mark it as the answer. Or, if you're expecting a more detailed one, at least up-vote it, if you found it useful.